# logo image error nextjs notion starter kit with teamspace

Tags: web, next.js, notion-js

I make a notion website with notion start kit
I use its notion page in my teamspace. However. the page main logo does not appear.

my website: https://futurocultor.minw.me

https://www.notion.so/image/https%3A%2F%2Fprod-files-secure.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com%2Fc8ff15de-5209-4476-8c03-724b60ebd2ba%2F11eb9b22-0a83-4d75-b373-954e59c4c4cf%2FIMG_0098.png?***table=team***&id=245d38e1-61d2-4532-8603-d29be899e962&cache=v2

I think its file url the **table=team** occurs error. When I change **“table=team”** to **table=block** in web inspector, It appears.
How can I solve it?